# Unable to make epplus working with unity and standalone mac build

Tags: unity-game-engine, epplus

I'm working on a project where i have to produce reports of worked hours by employes. 
Actually i'm able to use epplus with a build in windows and everything work fine. But it'S impossible to make it work on mac.
Here is the error i have in the unity editor when i try to generate the reports:

```
DllNotFoundException: user32.dll
System.Drawing.KnownColorTable.SystemColorToArgb (Int32 index)
System.Drawing.KnownColorTable.UpdateSystemColors (System.Int32[] colorTable)
System.Drawing.KnownColorTable.InitColorTable ()
System.Drawing.KnownColorTable.EnsureColorTable ()
System.Drawing.KnownColorTable.KnownColorToArgb (KnownColor color)
System.Drawing.Color.get_Value ()
System.Drawing.Color.ToArgb ()
OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelColor.SetColor (Color color)
```

I've tried many ways to make it working like :
https://answers.unity.com/questions/158983/how-do-you-load-systemdrawingdll-and-gdiplusdll-on.html

I've installed mono and the mono-libgdiplus library .

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please provide more information (e.g. command) to help users reproduce the error.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to get EPPlus to work with some modifications to the source code, where you remove the references to System.Drawing.

.NET is open source so you could add some of the classes from the System.Drawing namespace like Color. Image and Font will be harder to re-implement.

Comment: I know this is old but how do I add color from System.Drawing?

Comment: @PeterK It's available [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Color.cs)

If you want a rough version which works in Unity as an example, I made a [Fork of EPPlus](https://github.com/Flunx/EPPlus/tree/unity/EPPlus)

Comment: Thanks @Flunx, may I ask how to install this?

Comment: @PeterK Build the EPPlus solution. Import the EPPlus-unity.dll into your project. Note that not all features will be there, like Images and Font related features E.g. auto size columns.

Answer (score 1):

I always warn people every time I notice they are using `System.Drawing` in Unity. Yes, it will work on Windows and this will make you believe everything is fine but it will not work anywhere else.

This is because `System.Drawing` depends on some DLL's from *C:\Windows\System32* and other Windows directory..You will need to do a complete re-write of these DLL's to get them work on anything else other than Windows.

Even with mono-libgdiplus library you will still run into another problem with it in Unity. Find another *API that doesn't depend on `System.Drawing`*.

If all you need is epplus in Unity you can actually implement your own API to display the excel data with Unity's `InputField` UI component then use *libreoffice* to load it. If you can't do yourself then consider using one made by another person. [Here](https://github.com/kimsama/Unity-QuickSheet) is one from the github.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i will investigate on other solutions. And thanks for the link but i need to create excel file not read from it.